# UITextChecker is what dictionary?

Tags: ios, ios4, dictionary

Does anybody know what dictionary **UITextChecker** pulls from? I use it to verify that a word is in fact a valid word in an app. I have some questions from users about why specific words are available in other games (Boggle/Scrabble) but not in mine.

**Examples**: ai, qi, qat, xu, ae, tae, ait, ain, lav, aa, shh, za

I checked against */usr/share/dict/words* and none of these words are in **Websters Second International**, so maybe UITextChecker uses this same source? They do show up in other dictionaries online (but this is really besides the point of the post).

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UITextChecker may be using the same dictionary that UIReferenceLibraryViewController uses. In which case, you could use something like [UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm: @"term"] and if it returns true the word exists. I'm not sure how complete the built in dictionary is however.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it uses the iPhone dictionary of the user, which depends on the current language/NSLocale the user is using (which is set in the "International" Settings on the iPhone). This is the behavior we observe when typing some text anywhere in the iPhone, words underlined in read (because detected by the internal UITextChecker) depends on the locale used.

If the user have activated multiple keyboards with different languages each (e.g. a French AZERTY keyboard and an US QWERTY keyboard) it depends obviously on the current language, namely the current keyboard active at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the wordfeud dictionary... (that would be the only game I know those words from). They check their words from an online dictionary on their own server. Must be a list parsed from another spelling site or something.

I sometimes doubt the validity of some words though....